# Django logging to multiple files at once even with RotatingFileHandler?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-logging

I am using Django with logging config as follow:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version':1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{asctime} {process:d} {thread:d} {levelname} {name} {module} {funcName} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': BASE_DIR+'/logs/django_logs.log',
            'backupCount': 14,
            'maxBytes': 52428800,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        }
    },
}
```

I am running 16 processes of django, few daphne for websockets and few gunicorn processess for normal API calls based on django rest framework. But when I am looking at logs, multiple files are getting logged at once. For example, django_logs.1 .... django.logs.14 are getting logged into simultaneously. Do I have to add something else to log to one file at once and rotate it only when it's size exceed the specified size of log file?

For extra info, I am using python 3.6.8 and I initialize logger in each project file as follow:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docs.python.logging-cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from
>   multiple threads in a single process is supported, **logging to a single
>   file from multiple processes is not supported**, because there is no
>   standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple
>   processes in Python. If you need to log to a single file from multiple
>   processes, one way of doing this is to have all the processes log to a
>   [`SocketHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SocketHandler), and have a separate process which implements a socket
>   server which reads from the socket and logs to file. (If you prefer,
>   you can dedicate one thread in one of the existing processes to
>   perform this function.)

A complete example of this approach is detailed also in the cookbook. [See this section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#network-logging).

The docs also suggest a few alternatives to this approach:

> Alternatively, you can use a `Queue` and a [`QueueHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.QueueHandler) to send all
>   logging events to one of the processes in your multi-process
>   application

I've tested your logging configuration and it's working as expected when an unique process is logging to file handler. The file should rotate only when `maxBytes` is reached